# Cannot rename the downloaded file

Tags: node.js

The Express version is **4.16.4**

I downloaded a file :

```
... <a href="' + url + '" title="T&eacute;l&eacute;charger la facture"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>

router.get("/downloadfacturemaintenance/:facture", function (req, res) {
    var facture = req.params.facture;
    res.download(path.join(__dirname, '../config/uploads/facture_maintenance/'+facture), "facture.png", function (err) {

        console.log(err);

    });
});
```

At runtime the download starts. But the filename in the download is the filename in the first parameter of `res.download` ; although I defined an alternate name in the second parameter. But this second parameter is not considered ! So why ?

**edit :**

here is code :

```
router.post("/maintenancereparation", function (req, res) {
    async.parallel({
        types_vehicule: function (cb_types_vehicule) {
            connexion.query("select type_vehicule_id, type_vehicule_lib from " + utils.getPrefixNomTables() + "type_vehicule order by type_vehicule_id", function (err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                cb_types_vehicule(null, rows);
            });
        },
        maintenances: function (cb_maintenance) {
            connexion.query("select m.maintenance_id, m.maintenance_date_fin, v.immatriculation, m.maintenance_terminee, m.maintenance_facture from " + utils.getPrefixNomTables() + "maintenance m join " + utils.getPrefixNomTables() + "vehicule v on m.vehicule_id = v.vehicule_id order by m.maintenance_terminee, m.maintenance_date_fin", function (err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                cb_maintenance(null, rows);
            });
        }
    }, function (err, results) {
        res.render("maintenancereparation", { "types_vehicule": results.types_vehicule, "maintenances_new": results.maintenances });
    });
});

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="fr">
    <head>
        <style>
            .center {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frm" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Maintenance / R&eacute;paration</legend>
                <div class="row form-group col-sm-12">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="type_action" id="action_maintenance" /> Maintenance</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="type_action" id="action_reparation" /> Demande de r&eacute;paration</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="div_maintenance">
                    <table class="table" id="list_maintenance">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>V&eacute;hicule</th>
                                <th>Date fin maintenance</th>
                                <th style="background: #FFDD00 !important; font-size: 13px !important;">Actions</th>
                                <th>Closed</th>
                                <th>facture</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <% maintenances_new.forEach(function(maintenance){ %>
                            <tr>
                                <td><%= maintenance.immatriculation %></td>
                                <td><%= maintenance.maintenance_date_fin %></td>
                                <td><%= maintenance.maintenance_id %></td>
                                <td><%= maintenance.maintenance_terminee %></td>
                                <td><%= maintenance.maintenance_facture %></td>
                            </tr>
                            <% }) %>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div id="div_repair">
                    <div class="row form-group col-sm-12">
                        <label class="col-sm-1">Type v&eacute;hicule</label>
                        <select id="type_vehicule" name="type_vehicule">
                            <option value="">-- S&eacute;lectionner --</option>
                            <% types_vehicule.forEach(function(type_vehicule){ %>
                            <option value="<%= type_vehicule.type_vehicule_id %>"><%= type_vehicule.type_vehicule_lib %></option>
                            <% }) %>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>

    </html>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(":radio[name='type_action']").on("change", function () {
                if ($("#action_maintenance").is(":checked")) {
                    $("#div_repair").hide();
                    $("#div_maintenance").show();
                } else {
                    $("#div_maintenance").hide();
                    $("#div_repair").show();
                }
            });
            $("#action_maintenance").prop("checked", true);
            $(":radio[name='type_action']").change();
            var list = $("#list_maintenance").DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "loadingRecords": "Veuillez patienter...",
                    "processing": "Veuillez patienter...",
                    "zeroRecords": "Aucun résultat",
                    "emptyTable": "Aucun résultat"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": 0, className: "center" },
                    { "data": 1, className: "center" }
                ],
                "columnDefs": [
                    {
                        "targets": 1,
                        "render": function (data, type, row) {
                            return ( data == "" ? "" : (new Date(data)).toLocaleDateString() );
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [2],
                        orderable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, row) {
                            if (row[3] == 1) {
                                var facture = row[4];
                                var fichier = facture.substring(facture.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                                var ext = fichier.substring(fichier.lastIndexOf("."));
                                //fichier = fichier.substring(0, fichier.indexOf("_"));
                                var url = "/track/vehicule/downloadfacturemaintenance/"+fichier;
                                return '<a href="' + url + '" data-facture="' + row[4] + '" title="T&eacute;l&eacute;charger la facture"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>';
                            }
                            else
                                return '<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="' + data + '" data-vehicule="' + row[0] + '" title="Cl&ocirc;turer"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        targets: [3,4],
                        orderable: false,
                        searchable: false,
                        visible:false
                    }
                ]
            });
            list.on("click", "a[data-id]", function () {
                var pk = $(this).data("id"), vehicule = $(this).data("vehicule");
                $("#george_content").load("/track/vehicule/clotureMaintenance/" + pk + "/" + vehicule);
            });
        });
    </script>

    router.get("/downloadfacturemaintenance/:facture", function (req, res) {
        var facture = req.params.facture;
        var fichier = facture.substring(facture.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        var ext = fichier.substring(fichier.lastIndexOf("."));
        fichier = fichier.substring(0, fichier.indexOf("_"));
        res.download(path.join(__dirname, '../config/uploads/facture_maintenance/'+facture), "facture.png", function (err) {

            console.log(err);

        });
    });
```

Comment: From what client are you executing the request to this route?
If from a browser, did you try "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" in your browser? When trying to replicate the problem locally, simply updating the app code and reloading the app but not refreshing the cache/hard reloading the browser results in the 'old' file name being downloaded.

Comment: it is from a Google Chrome web browser.

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me

```
app.get('/download', function(req, res){
      const file = `${__dirname}/demo.jpg`;
      //res.attachment()
      res.download(file,"DEMO.jpg"); // Set disposition and send it.
    });
```

If it's not working probably due to caching, clear browser cache, It should work then. I was also facing the same problem when I tried replicating the issue and it turned out there is nothing wrong with code. Then I opened a browser in incognito mode, it worked as expected.

**Check response header `Content-Disposition` in both cases:**

When you don't pass `filename` as the second arg to `res.download`:

[image]

Passing filename as the second argument:

[image]

Tested in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating this problem with this code: https://github.com/alexkubica/stackoverflow-example-express-download-with-filename-parameter

I suspected at first that maybe it has something to do with you traversing up the directories but it worked just fine.

Is it possible for you to upload your code so we can debug it?
I'll try looking into it and update this answer once I come with a solution.

Comment: @pheromix post a git repository that I can clone and run conveniently

Comment: but there are database access which you cannot access due to security reason.

Comment: I run the app in Firefox and it works , but with Google Chrome the problem raised ! So why ?

Comment: @pheromix which chrome version do you have? It works for me in chrome too

Comment: Google Chrome 79.0.3945.130 (Build officiel) (64 bits)